# Dual boot re-install

Tags: dual-boot

I am not very proficient in Linux, but I tinker some. I have an old PC that I installed Ubuntu 10.04 and Windows XP to dual boot.  I don't remember how I did it, but it works fine.  It seems to me that I had use a different boot disc tool to do it.   I would now like to get rid of the old Ubuntu and install Debian Wheezy.

If I boot from the Debian ISO, and choose the partition on which Ubuntu resides, will it overwrite?  And will the boot menu/boot loader automatically update?

I am paranoid about wiping it out.  I use this PC for a CNC router table.

Comment: If system that important you must have full backup of the entire system. What will you do when hardware fails? So backup vital. With Ubuntu the Something Else install option and choosing the existing / (root) installs to just that partition. Not sure with Debian and this is an Ubuntu Forum.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do, 100%, is to back up your machine using something like CloneZilla. This will create a complete clone of your hard drive, including all boot partitions and stuff. In the long run, you'll likely hugely appreciate doing this, as your CNC router table will continue to function.

After that, sure, you should just be able to boot from the Debian ISO and choose the partition that Ubuntu lives on. You might need to delete some partitioning if bits of it were separated out at installation, in which instance you need to be careful not to delete the Windows boot manager. If you delete the GRUB loader, that's fine, you can replace it and add Windows to it later without any complications.

After that, if anything does go wrong, CloneZilla will come to the rescue and restore the machine to its exact state before the upgrade.